# Update parent variables from inside a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, parent-child

I am trying to update the parent `var a` inside the html page I am hardcoding and then alerting it outside but the value doesn't change.
This is inside my content.js

```
var a;
function popUpWindow() {
    a="Nothing";
    alert(a);// Displays "Nothing"
    myWindow = window.open("Accept", "myWindow", "width=450, height=300");
    myWindow.document.write(
      "<html>"+
      "<head>"+
        "<script> function closeWindow(){parent.a =\"Something\"; alert(\"a has been updated\");  window.close();}</script>"+
      "</head>"+
      "<body>"+
          "<form>"+
              "<div id=leadinformation>"+
                  "<p id=titleParagraph>You are about to create a new Lead:</p>"+
                  "First Name....."+ "<input type=text id=firstname value="+firstname+">" +"<br>"+
                  "Last Name....."+ "<input type=text id=lastname value="+lastname+">" +"<br>"+
                  "Title:..............."+ "<input type=text id=position value="+positions[0]+">" +"<br>"+
                  "Company:......"+ "<input type=text id=company value="+companies[0]+">" +"<br>"+
                  "Email:............"+ "<input type=text id=email value="+email+">" +"<br>"+
                  "Phone:..........."+ "<input type=text nid=phonenumber value="+phonenumber+">" +"<br>"+"<br>"+
              "<div>"+

              "<button id=Accept onClick=closeWindow() >Accept</button>"+
              "<button id=Close onClick=closeWindow() >Close</button>"+
          "</form>"+
          "</div>"+
      "</body>"+
      "</html>" 
    );

    myWindow.document.getElementById('Accept').onclick=addToLeads;
    myWindow.document.getElementById('Close').onclick=Close;
}

function Close() {
    alert(a);
    //Displays "Nothing" (Should have been "Soomething")
}
```

Inside the html page I am setting the `parent.a` to "Something" and  I `alert(a)` which displays "Something".
Then I `alert(a)` again inside the `Close()` function, which is outside the html page but now `alert(a)` displays "Nothing" again.

Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: Is alert("a has been updated"); being fired?

Comment: yes it is being fired; I event checked alert(a) afterwards and it was set to "Smthing" which was fine, but outside the page it was back to "Nothing"

Comment: Is this code contained within another function at all, or is it within the global scope?

Comment: the popUpWindow() function is being triggered when the user clicks on a button I created before and  being inserted in the current DOM

Comment: So your popup window tries to call a function from the content script? Those are isolated contexts so it won't work.

Comment: Yes I call the Close() function inside the popup window, the call is being made but the display is still "Nothing" when it should have been "Something"

Answer (score 1):

Change `parent.a` to `a` in the sub function:

```
"<head>"+
        "<script> function closeWindow(){a =\"Something\"; alert(\"a has been updated\");  window.close();}</script>"+
"</head>"+
```

Comment: I tried to change it now, but it has the exact same effect as before

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create an iframe, so `parent` looks wrong to me here. Try `window.opener.a` instead.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion but it has  the same effect as before

Comment: if I do alert(windoe.opener.a) before I set the value for it it displays "undefined"   :(